# When asking a question indirectly, should I still put the verb first?

Tags: questions

For example, what is correct:

- Can you also tell me where I can find...

or

- Can you also tell me where can I find...

Comment: Subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions) don't normally have subject/aux inversion so your first example is fine. Apparently, some varieties of English (mostly AmE) allow such interrogatives with inversion in contexts of strong question-orientation. They would allow your second example.